# Drawing an UML abstract class on the paper without italic?

Tags: java, uml, abstract, handwriting

How should I represent an abstract class (in Java) in an UML diagram drawn by hand on the paper without using italic font?

Answer (score 8):

The annotation `{abstract}` below the classname can be used.

Should look like this:

```
+---------------+
|   Classname   |
|   {abstract}  |
+---------------+
```

UML specs p. 99:

> The name of an abstract Classifier is shown in italics, where permitted by the font in use. Alternatively or in addition, an abstract Classifier may be shown using the textual annotation {abstract} after or below its name.

Comment: May `{abstract}` also be used for abstract operations of the class ?

Comment: aren't guillemets («») the right way to designate the abstract keyword?

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would just write `abstract Foo` as title if you cannot use italic.